# Update or create new row based on Unique ID Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste, lookup, unique-id

I have found a few options that come close to what I want to do, but nothing matching it exactly.

---

The request is simple enough.

"Sheet A" - Master Sheet (has 1 header row)

"Sheet B" - Input Sheet (has 1 header row)

"Column C" - Unique ID (same column on both sheets)

---

**Trigger**

- Sheet B is edited

**Actions**

- Script finds the Unique ID from Sheet B in Column C and looks for it in Sheet A in Column C.
- If it finds it, the *entire respective row* on Sheet A is *replaced* with the *entire respective row* from Sheet B.
- If it does not find it, a new row is added at the bottom of Sheet A and the *entire respective row* from Sheet B is added as a new record into the new row at the bottom of Sheet A.
- The *entire respective row* on Sheet B is Deleted.

Actions repeat until there are no populated rows in Sheet B from row 2 on (i.e. excluding the row 1 header).

Thanks

**Edits**

1. For clarification on why I am looking to do this. I have a Form that is being submitted and sending the data through to Google Sheets (Cognito -> Zapier -> Google Sheets). Part of this form involves repeating sections (line items). The current method that is importing the responses has no issue with adding new responses correctly, however when a response is updated, it cannot find/update the existing row(s) correctly for the repeating sections. So I had the intention of using Sheet A as my master sheet and then using Sheet B to simply be a receiving sheet. This way I can just submit every entry (including updated ones) as a "new" entry on Sheet B, and then have my script do the updating.
2. Sheet B will be edited automatically every time a new form entry is submitted or updated. The "edit" is basically a new row being added and data being populated into that row. It may be a good idea to add a 1 minute timer to the trigger so that if there is lots of data being added that it gives time for that to happen.
3. I am not even remotely close to a script expert. I just browse around different scripts other people have made and try to combine them to get them to work for what I need. I have found scripts that will move a row over and then delete it, but it does not check for matching values to update. I have found other scripts that check for unique values and copy over, but they do not delete the original row on the other sheet. I have tried to combine them, but since I don't have the base knowledge, I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: It's possible with onChange or onEdit. Probably onEdit is easier because there is more info about your current location in the event object.

Comment: I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for this. So can I ask you about your goal? 1. About `Sheet B is edited`, how will you edit it? For example, the values including several rows are copy and pasted? 2. About `The entire respective row on Sheet B is Deleted.`, in this case, the Sheet B always has only one header row? Under this situation, the values are put to the Sheet B? 3. Can I ask you about the current issue of your script?

Comment: When you mentioned that Sheet B and Sheet A have column C in common my first thought was "why don't you just insert the new record" but it turns out you are treating Sheet B - Column C as a queue-like. can you confirm this? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. I'll answer them with an edit in my question since 500 characters in this reply is not going to be enough.

Comment: It'd be helpful for the community if we had the type of data you have in your sheet B and Sheet A. Can you share a similar Spreadsheet without sensitive data?

Comment: @JoseVasquez -  My work account does not allow me to make a sheet public. The code I would be looking for would need to be universal anyways as I would actually be copying it across a number of different sheets that capture different information. A sample sheet can be literally anything, the only requirement is that Sheet A and Sheet B have matching header rows. The data contained could span every type of data that Google Sheets allows (dates, text, numbers, alphanumeric, currency, percentage, time, etc.). The one thing I can confirm, is that the Unique ID would **always** be 9 numeric digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### As a workaround I'd use the onEdit simple trigger and a O(n) search

Here's my approach:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // If it's not the Sheet B it won't make changes
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() !== "Sheet B") {
    return;
  }

  var range = e.range;
  var numberRow = range.getA1Notation().slice(1);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetA = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet A");
  var sheetB = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet B");

  var currentRowB = sheetB.getRange(`A${numberRow}:D${numberRow}`);
  var id = currentRowB.getValues()[0][2];
  // There's to be 4 values in the row (no empty values)
  if(currentRowB.getValues()[0].filter(value => value !== '').length === 4) {

    // Get all the values in Sheet A
    var rows = sheetA.getDataRange().getValues();
    for (row=1; row < rows.length; row++) {
      // If column C matches the ID replace the row
      if(rows[row][2] === id) {
        var currentRowA = sheetA.getRange(`A${row+1}:D${row+1}`);
        currentRowA.setValues(currentRowB.getValues());
        currentRowB.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
        return;
      }
    }

    // If the ID doesn't match then insert a new row
    var newRow = sheetA.getRange(`A${rows.length+1}:D${rows.length+1}`);
    newRow.setValues(currentRowB.getValues());
    currentRowB.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
  }
}
```

Which meets the requirements you asked:

- Script finds the Unique ID from Sheet B in Column C and looks for it in Sheet A in Column C. **(line 19-28)**
- If it finds it, the entire respective row on Sheet A is replaced with the entire respective row from Sheet B. **(line 22-24)**
- If it does not find it, a new row is added at the bottom of Sheet A and the entire respective row from Sheet B is added as a new record into the new row at the bottom of Sheet A. **(line 31-33)**
- The entire respective row on Sheet B is Deleted. **(line 22 and 33)**

I used this Sheet format as example:

[image]

Both Sheets have the same format. Keep in mind that this script checks if there's a valid row (in this specific case 4 columns which compose a row) before replacing it.

### As a different approach (handling blank data)

In a summary this script should run every X minutes or the time you want it doesn't matter if there's new data incoming because this code will handle all the data given a certain time.

I edited the code in order to use the Z1 cell as a blocker cell and a time based trigger:

**Trigger:**

[image]

**Code**

```
function processCells() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetA = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet A");
  var sheetB = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet B");

  // If it's not the Sheet B or if there's a process running it won't make changes
  if (sheetB.getName() !== "Sheet B" || sheetB.getRange("Z1") === "Running") {
    return;
  }

  // Use the Z1 cell in order to block or unblock this sheet
  sheetB.getRange("Z1").setValue('Running');

  // Process all the rows
  var numCells = sheetB.getDataRange().getValues().length + 1;
  for (numberRow = 2; numberRow <= numCells; numberRow++) {

    var currentRowB = sheetB.getRange(`A${numberRow}:D${numberRow}`);
    var id = currentRowB.getValues()[0][2];

    // Get all the values in Sheet A
    var rows = sheetA.getDataRange().getValues();
    var match = false;
    for (row=1; row < rows.length; row++) {
      // If column C matches the ID replace the row
      if(rows[row][2] === id) {
        var currentRowA = sheetA.getRange(`A${row+1}:D${row+1}`);
        currentRowA.setValues(currentRowB.getValues());
        currentRowB.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
        match = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if(!match) {
      // If the ID doesn't match then insert a new row
      var newRow = sheetA.getRange(`A${rows.length+1}:D${rows.length+1}`);
      newRow.setValues(currentRowB.getValues());
      currentRowB.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
    }
  }

  sheetB.getRange("Z1").setValue('');
}
```

Note that every time the script runs it'll check if there's another one processing the rows by using Z1.

[image]

### References

- [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Hey @Jose, I did a quick test and it is throwing an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (onEdit @ Code.gs:3)". I have ensured that my sheet names are exactly "Sheet A" and "Sheet B" and the only thing I changed in your code was from 4 columns to 6 instead on line 16.

On this note too: "There's to be 4 values in the row (no empty values)". Does that mean that I cannot have a blank data point? So in your screenshot, if Row 3 had nothing in column "B", would this code fail?

Comment: Hello, that's why I asked for a Sheet as example, because the code relies on how the INPUT data is. 4 values are just an example it could have 5 or more columns. Regarding the **cannot read property** error might be due because you are trying to run the code from the editor rather than edit a cell (keep in mind this is a simple trigger code). If you want to run this script manually after input data, let me know so I can modify the script. As you mentioned your input can have blank data it would be better if you had to run this code by hand (through API).

Comment: 1/2 Usually once I have code that functions in general I can adjust well enough to get it to work with my sheet format. Wasn't complaining about having to adjust the number of columns, was just mentioning it in case I accidentally broke something.

I had tested with edit without it working, but I just did it again and the trigger went through.

One thing I am still testing to see why it isn't working. If I copy/paste a whole row into Sheet B, the function fails saying that there was no "onEdit" event again. Is it just because I am copy/pasting, or because the entire row is entered at once?

Comment: 2/2 - I also tested the "blank data" scenario and it did not work. It still needs to work the same way, I was just emphasizing that the entire row won't always be populated.

Comment: Haven't done incredibly detailed testing yet, but it seems to be working excellent so far on all the base requirements (new/repeating/blank cells). Thank you VERY much!!!